# Mongoengine User Authentication

Tags: django, mongodb, authentication

Does anyone have specific examples of using the authentication from Mongoengine?

A couple questions I have are:

extending the User class

```
from mongoengine.django.auth import User
from mongoengine import *

class User(User):
    location =  GeoPointField()
```

When I create a user with no documents are saved

```
User.create_user('bob','bobpass','bobsaget@fullhouse.gov')
User.objects
>>>[]
```

explicitly call the .save() method has the same affect

Can the User class not be inherited?

Also

Is there a login() method like in the standard authentication backend?

I am starting to feel like I am trying to put a square peg in a round hole with MongoDB and Django...

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used MongoEngine, but I've been looking at it documentation.

First, don't use the `User` name for your extension, there could be name clashes. Call it for example `Profile`:

```
from mongoengine.django.auth import User
from mongoengine import *

class Profile(User):
    location =  GeoPointField()
```

If that is not working, try:

```
class Profile(Document):
    user = ReferenceField(User)
    location =  GeoPointField()
```

For your login question, [look at this](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django.html).

Answer (score 0):

create instance.

```
user = User.create_user('bob','bobpass','bobsaget@fullhouse.gov')
user.save()
```

or

```
user = User(username='bob', password='bobpass', email='bobsaget@fullhouse.gov')
user.save()
```

or

```
user = User()
user.username = 'bob'
user.password = 'bobpass'
user.email = 'bobsaget@fullhouse.gov'
user.save()
```